# scope is getting undefined inside the same controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have one controller for two views. I have a submit button in the first view and the html code is as below,

```
<div class="item item-stacked-label" ng-repeat="item in cartItems" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" ng-model="item.name" ng-class="{hideName: !setActive, showName: setActive}" ng-click="setActive = !setActive ">
            <p>{{item.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col" ng-model="item.qty" >{{item.qty}}</div>
        <div class="col" ng-model="item.price" >{{item.price}}</div>
        <div class="col" ng-click="removeItem(index)">X</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel2">
        <a class="social-button" >Purchase</a>
        <a class="social-button" ng-click="delivery(cartItems)" >Delivery</a>
    </div>
<div/>
```

In the controller ,

```
$scope.delivery = function(deliverItems){
    $scope.amount = $scope.getTotal();
    if (localStorage.getItem('appLocalStorageUser')!==null){
        var data = {
            appId : $rootScope.appId,
            item : deliverItems,
            amount : $scope.amount,
        };
        $scope.xx = data;
        $state.go('app.deliverDetails');
    }
    else
        $state.go('app.login');
 }
```

And in the second view html is as below,

```
<div class="item item-stacked-label">
    <div class="row2">
        <div>Name</div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="details.name" style="width:100%; height:20px; margin: 0px 10px; border: 1px groove gray;">
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div>Address</div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="details.address" style="width:100%; height:20px; margin: 0px 10px; border: 1px groove gray;">
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div>Contact number</div>
        <input type="number" ng-model="details.number" style="width:100%; height:20px; margin: 0px 10px; border: 1px groove gray;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel2">
    <a class="social-button" ng-click="deliver(details)" >Deliver</a>
</div>
```

In the same controller,below function is written to get submit details for the deliver button,

```
$scope.deliver = function(deliverDetails){
    console.log(deliverDetails);
    console.log($scope.xx);
}
```

The routes are as below,

```
.state('app.cart', {
    url: '/cart',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/cart.html',
          controller: 'cartCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.deliverDetails', {
      url: '/deliverDetails',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/deliverDetails.html',
            controller: 'cartCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
```

But the `$scope.xx` is getting undefined. I don't get this. Both the functions are in the same controller. Please help

Comment: Where is your controller in `html`?

Comment: both the functions are in the same controller

Comment: That's because $scope.xx isn't defined until $scope.delivery was called.

Comment: are you sure you passed by `$scope.delivrey` before and that `$scope.xx` is indeed not supposed to be undefined? Can you add an alert or a log when the value of `$scope.xx` is set and see if you go there before?

Comment: The delivery button is getting visible before the deliver button. So there is no way that the second function is getting executed before the first function.

Comment: $scope.delivery is going down the else path, debug to verify

Comment: No. it is not redirecting to the login and I checked it with a console.log. It is not going to the else part

Comment: you haven't provided enough code here for others to reproduce your issue, but based on the fact that you use `state.go('app.deliverDetails')` after setting `$scope.xx`, I suspect that `app.deliverDetails` is creating a new copy of your controller, not re-using the same instance.  We would need to see your routing config to be sure, however.

Comment: the edit with your routes confirms my suspicion.  Just because the two controllers share a reference to the same controller *code* does not mean they share a reference to the same controller *instance*.